Artifactory SSL certificate issue with Docker Hub
I have Artifactory 6.x running on-premise.  I created a remote repository and pointed it to Docker Hub (i.e.  https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/).  Then create an Artifactory virtual repo which has this remote repository.  When doing a docker pull, I got this:
error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=1: unknown blob
To fix this issue, I have tried to zap the caches in these repos.  Still not working.  When checking the Artifactory log, I see this:
2024-04-19 15:32:03,099 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:437) - dockerhub: Error in getting information for 'jfrogecosystem/jfrog-setup-cli/2.0.0/sha256__xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (Failed retrieving resource from https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/jfrogecosystem/jfrog-setup-cli/blobs/sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target).
I have imported the root/intermediate/server certificates in the Java keystore used by Artifactory, but still not working.  Anything I missed or did wrong here?  Thanks.
Import the certs into Java keystore.

Please check if this page helps you.
https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-resolve-the-issue-when-artifactory-fails-to-make-secure-connection-to-a-remote-url/issue

I followed the steps to import the certs and doesn’t work.  I did that to the Java Artifactory uses.
